# Using okhttp3 library with react-native (throws an exception when running the command of 'react-native run-android')

Tags: android, react-native, build.gradle, okhttp

I've been developing a `native-module` to use in my `react-native` project.
And my native module uses `okhttp3` library.

However when I run the command of `react-native run-android` I get the following exception:

```
Unknown source file : UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
Unknown source file : com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lokhttp3/Address;
```

I guess both of `react-native` and I add `okhttp3` library to use in the same app.

Is there any chance to use `okhttp3` library which is added by `react-native`?

or is there any chance to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question on `react-native` [github site](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/8535) has been responded.

The issue was regarding with `build.gradle`.

Adding the line of `compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.3.1'` to the `dependencies` part of `build.gradle` file was worked.